# Instagram DM doesn't show wordpress website's image

Tags: wordpress, instagram

I made a website using Wordpress and astra theme and setting SEO & meta tag.

When I sent my website's link in Instagram DM, I can't see preview image for my website.

[Instagram DM Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzGsD.jpg)

I already set meta og:image, and og:image:secure_url as well.

Does anyone know how to fix?

Any answer helps me. Thank you!

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score -2):

Your current HTML code is this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content=".../wp-content/uploads/2024/03/소셜이미지.png" />
```

Do not use special characters in file names (and directories). It is recommended to use only English lowercase letters and hyphen characters.

```
<meta property="og:image" content=".../wp-content/uploads/2024/03/file-name.png" />
```

Comment: You're welcome @sodayellos. It would be better to add the previous HTML to the question. And you can mark the answer as "solution".